# Best websites for design patterns?

Tags: design-patterns

What is the best website for design patterns?

I really like the format of http://ajaxpatterns.org

Are there other sites for general programming patterns organized in the same way?

Answer (score 7):

One website that I often use is [101 Design Patterns](http://sourcemaking.com/design_patterns)

However, if you somehow change your thought and look for a book...
I recommend you [Head First: Design Patterns](http://headfirstlabs.com/books/hfdp/)

It gives really good descriptions and actual code examples for each design pattern.
Patterns that are discussed in this book are often used in practices
For example, I read up on decorator, different factory patterns, MVC, singleton, proxy, etc.

Comment: +1 for the Head First plug.  I love those books.

Comment: @Refracted Paladin: They are awesome, because they have so many pictures! haha...most of the time, I don't feel like I'm reading :)

Answer (score 4):

For web sites and web applications, http://developer.yahoo.com/ypatterns/

For the "original" Gang Of Four software patterns: http://www.dofactory.com/Patterns/Patterns.aspx

Comment: dofactory is wonderful website, it is really recommended

Answer (score 2):

Wikipedia has an article on design patterns and discusses several patterns in various levels of detail.  It's not organized in quite the same way. Here's the link:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Design_pattern_(computer_science)

Answer (score 1):

For applications using the Microsoft stack: [Pattern and Practices Developer Center](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/practices/default.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

[Here](http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/) are the patterns from the book "**Patterns of Enterprise Application Architecture**" by Martin Fowler.

[Here](http://www.enterpriseintegrationpatterns.com/) are the patterns from the book "**Enterprise Integration Patterns**" by Gregor Hohpe and Bobby Woolf

Comment: I believe all of the patterns in Fowler's book, Patterns of Enterprise Application Architecture, are documented on this site.

Answer (score 1):

Good site for unit-test related design patterns: http://xunitpatterns.com/

Answer (score 1):

A comprehensive guide about design patterns can be found at http://www.oodesign.com/

One of the nice book for design patterns is **Head First Design Patterns**.

Answer (score 0):

UX Patterns Explorer - http://quince.infragistics.com/

Answer (score 0):

This is a great [site](http://www.vincehuston.org/dp/).  It shows what the code looks like before the design pattern is applied, and what it looks like after.  This is very useful for just starting to learn patterns and refactoring.

Answer (score 0):

Check this out http://www.blackwasp.co.uk/DesignPatternsArticles.aspx
I found it very useful for reference.

If you are planning to learn design patterns from scratch, I suggest following books
1. Head first - OOAD
2. Head first - Design patterns
3. Refactoring by Martin Fowler
4. Design patterns by GOF (need more time to read)

Answer (score 0):

- Simple Design Pattern Website : http://sourcemaking.com/design_patterns
- A complete Design Pattern Website : http://www.dofactory.com/Patterns/Patterns.aspx